# What is returned by Raster.getPixels()?

Tags: java, awt, raster, imaging

What is returned in [`getPixels()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html#getPixels(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20double[]))? I see no information in the doc. How color data is represented? How is it laid out, by row or by column?

Answer (score 0):

the data is represented:
int red
int green
int blue
int alpha